# Generate a list representing a doorbell system

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I'm trying to generate a list from two `Int`s and another list of tuples to represent a doorbell system for an apartment building. The first number is the number of floors, the second number is the floor that "doesn't exist"/we jump, and the list is the distribution of the apartments for floor. For example:

```
geneList 10 4 [("Rgt", 10), ("Lft", 8), ("Cent", 3)]
```

(In this example, we will have 10 floors and the 4th doesn't exist. Only the first three have 'Cent' 'Rgt' and 'Lft' apartments. Floors from fifth to ninth only have 'Rgt' and 'Left' apartments. Floors from 10 to 11 only have 'Rght' apartments.)

The return value must be:

```
["1Rgt","1Lft","1Cent","2Rgt","2Lft","2Cent","3Rgt","3Lft","3Cent","5Rgt","5Lft","6Rgt","6Lft","7Rgt","7Lft","8Rgt","8Lft","9Rgt","9Lft","10Rgt","11Rgt"]
```

I have tried different ways, but I never managed to reach the result.

My last attempt was:

```
geneList :: Int -> Int -> [(Char, Int)] -> [Char]
geneList 0 _ _ = []
geneList x y xs = [a++b | a <- [1..x+1], b <- xs, (\=) a y]
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Shouldn't the last element in the expected result be `11Rgt`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question correctly, but if the `snd` number in each tuple represents how many floors this 'side' exist, isn't the first parameter to `geneList` (`x`) redundant?

Comment: You should also post the output of your failed attempt.

Comment: @MarkSeemann yes it should be 11Rgt, i corrected it now, thx.
The first parameter is to make it more simple, i think, like if i try geneList 0 3 [('N',3), ('S',1)] its impossible or if i try somthing like geneList 3 10 [('A',3), ('B',3)] the return will be ["1A","1B",""2A","2B","3A","3B"].
I don't know if i make myself clear

Comment: What should `geneList 4 10 [('A',3), ('B',3)]` return?

Comment: @MarkSeemann ["1A","1B","2A,"2B","3A","3B"]

Comment: IOW, the `4` is never used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let’s work out the number to write for a floor:

```
floorNum skip n = if n < skip then n else n + 1
```

Now let’s get the apartment names for a floor name

```
apartments :: [(String, Int)] -> Int -> Int -> [String]
apartments spec skip floor = [f ++ name | (name, max) <- spec, floor <= max]
  where f = show $ floorNum skip floor
```

And we can collect these for all the floors:

```
geneList floors skip spec = [name | floor <- [1..floors], name <- apartments spec skip floor]
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the problems in your code:

1. The type of `"Rgt"` is `String` (a.k.a. `[Char]`), not `Char`.
2. The not-equal comparison operator is written `/=`, not `\=`. (read the documentation carefully!)
3. You didn't make sure that the current floor is at most the height of each apartment.
4. When you write `b <- xs`, `b` is a `(String, Int)` tuple. You should write `(apartment_name, apartment_height) <- xs` instead.

Comment: I won't post the complete code, rather, only a few hints.

Comment: @onegirl This is Stack Overflow, [it's not recommended to write a thank you in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment), you should [vote on and accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  instead.